How to resolve `ValueError: Error apply transform "left join"` when joining 3 BigQuery tables in Dataflow using Job builder?
I have 3 tables from a BigQuery dataset as data sources: tableA, tableB, tableC. I am trying to join tableA and tableB on column idAB and tableB and tableC on column idBC. I am using a Join transform, with all the tables as the input steps, and the join equalities as specified:

tableA.idAB=tableB.idAB
tableB.idBC=tableC.idBC

However, I am getting the following error:
ValueError: Error apply transform "left join" at line 15: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 10; 2 is required

My sink is also another BigQuery table. How do I resolve this?

Hi @dbkpoop, Check it seems to be mismatching the key value pairs of dictionaty and also refer these link1 and link2.
